# How did a 1 rep user post a comment?

Tags: bug, comments, reputation

How did this 1 rep user ([Phillip Mitchell](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/334696/phillip-mitchell)) who has asked no questions and posted no answers manage to post a comment?

[Opposite of benefit of the doubt?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/118368/#comment1168193_118368)

Is this a bug?

Comment: Closely connected but posted on MSE: [Should I flag a comment if it is posted by someone who has only 1 rep?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/272199)

Answer (score 3):

No, it’s not a bug. This one has a simple answer:

[image: image of deleted answer and notice]

Comment: Hmm. Why'd you convert it to a comment? It's clearly an answer. It's also clearly a terrible answer. Wouldn't it have been better to let it get downvoted into oblivion?

Comment: @CJDennis It *was* downvoted into oblivion. It was at `–3` when I deleted it.

Comment: @CJDennis One-line responses offering opinion without substantiation are comments, whether they’re posted in the answer box or elsewhere.